# Converting Array to Object for selecting objects (Refactoring / Optimizing)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

While I was facing slow loading time when it iterate **array** to render objects, I want to change its data structure. I show table of contents for seasons. When user clicks an item, the item is marked as selected.

Here is current data structure (**Array**)

```
const seasons = [{
  id: 6,
  value: 'All',
}, {
  id: 7,
  value: 'Spring',
}, {
  id: 8,
  value: 'Summer',
}, {
  id: 9,
  value: 'Fall',
}, {
  id: 10,
  value: 'Winter',
}];
```

I'm storing selected Season Ids as an Array now

```
state = {selectedSeasonIds: []}
```

When `selectedSeasonIds` has `id`, I want to remove the `id` from it. Otherwise, add the `id` to `selectedSeasonIds`. (**This is current approach**)

```
if(_.includes(this.state.selectedSeasonIds, id)) {
    let newSelectedSeasonIds = _.filter(this.state.selectedSeasonIds, (curObject) => {
        return curObject !== id;
    });
    this.setState({selectedSeasonIds : newSelectedSeasonIds});
} else {
    let newSelectedSeasonIds = [...this.state.selectedSeasonIds, id];
    this.setState({selectedSeasonIds : newSelectedSeasonIds});
}
```

And here is my pseudo-code for refactoring to convert my arrays to object structure for performance. (I found searching on an object is MUCH faster than searching on the array)

Changing the array to object

```
const seasons = {
    6 :{
      id: 6,
      value: 'All',
    },
    7: {
      id: 7,
      value: 'Spring',
    }, 
    8: {
      id: 8,
      value: 'Summer',
    },
    9: {
      id: 9,
      value: 'Fall',
    }, 
    10: {
      id: 10,
      value: 'Winter',
    }
};
```

Changing Selected Seasons <- I want to store only the key(id) of the objects. But I want to use it as an object

```
state = {selectedSeasonIds : {}} Can I store object type state?
```

Here is expected logic which can be 50 times faster than array search.

```
if(selectedSeasonIds[id]) {
    //remove
    return _.omit(state.selectedSeasonIds, id); < is this right?
} else {
    //add
    return {...state.selectedSeasonIds, [id]:id} <- Does this look ok?
}
```

Well if you think this is right, you can copy and paste my code to the answer (I will edit my question too).

Otherwise, Can you provide better suggestion or find the error?

Thank you so much

Comment: Can't you just store a `selected` prop in each `season` object and get rid of `selectedSeasonIds`? Or do you need both?

Comment: Actually that is great question. But I think I would rather keep both because... let's say two screen calls same object `season`, and it will show wrong information because it's supposed for each screen to have different `selectedSeasonIds`. (This is my opinion. What do you think?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you have to loop through `seasons` in order to render them.

My first suggestion is to add `selected` prop in each one of them so you don't have to check in `selectedSeasonsIds` on every render.

In case this is not an option, you can still keep the `key` `value` approach.

```
onAdd(id) {
  this.setState({
    selectedSeasonsIds: {
      ...this.state.selectedSeasonsIds,
      [id]: this.state.selectedSeasonsIds[id] ? false : true 
    }
  })
}
```

When checking for specific season whether they are selected or not, simply:

```
render() {
  const { seasons, selectedSeasonsIds } = this.state

  return (
    <div>
      ...
      {Object.keys(seasons).map(key =>
        <ItemComponent
          {...propsThatYouMightNeed}
          selected={selectedSeasonsIds[key]}
        />
      )}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Your guess is correct. Thanks for reading my question carefully.

Comment: So how should I store my default selectedSeason Ids? selectedSeasonIds  = {6: false, 7:false, 8:false, 9:false, 10:false} <- Is this right?

Comment: That correct :) Store the values as boolean so you don't have to check whether they exist or not on each iteration.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this? I'd recommend storing arrays and then converting as necessary for lookups.

```js
const seasons = [{
  id: 6,
  value: 'All',
}, {
  id: 7,
  value: 'Spring',
}, {
  id: 8,
  value: 'Summer',
}, {
  id: 9,
  value: 'Fall',
}, {
  id: 10,
  value: 'Winter',
}];

const seasonsHash = _.keyBy(seasons, 'id');

// check for existence
const hasId = _.has(seasonsHash, id)

// remove and convert back to array
_.values(_.omit(seasonsHash, id))

// add new id
_.concat(_.values(seasonsHash), id)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Wow very creative. Thanks! I'll need it in case that I don't want to convert them all.